# Incorrect path to my file when I try to restart it

Tags: python, python-os

I am trying to execute this:

`os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)`

The result I am getting:

`C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'c:\\Users\\user\\OneDrive\\Рабочий'`

As you can see, the path after the 'module in' words is improper. I printed sys.argv and got:

`c:/Users/user/OneDrive/Рабочий стол/myfolder/file.py`

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the [`os.exec*` family](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execv) and not the [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) ?

Comment: There's a space in the path, so you have to add quotes.

Comment: @ljmc yeah i need os.exec family cuz it ends the current process

Comment: @Matthias where should i add quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to `os.execv` into another program passed in the command line:

```py
# as execv_argv.py
import os
import sys

os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable] + sys.argv[1:])
```

and call with

```bash
python execv_argv.py "second exec.py"
```

Note `os.execv` with full `sys.argv` will call the parent again forever.

Comment: Well actually i was trying to restart the same file after getting update event from watchdog, thank you for the answer

Comment: replacing my execv with yours didn't help, it is now searching for wrong directory

Comment: My `execv_argv.py` and the other executable are in the same directory, I don't know where your function that would call `execv` is compared to your main file.

Comment: Plus if the watchdog finds an error with your program, then I would not recommend having the same program restart itself, have something else kick it back up.

Comment: I am using vscode to start my file using:
& "C:/Program Files/Python310/python.exe" "c:/Users/user/OneDrive/Рабочий стол/folder/onchange.py"

Comment: Ok, can I use subprocess.call instead? Will it replace current process?

Comment: `subprocess` will launch a new process not replace the current one, but this scheduling and replacement is sounding more and more like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Then how can I restart the script(like uvicorn or gunicorn) on file change?

Comment: You mean like [gunicorn's `--reload` flag](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#reload) or [uvicorn's `--reload` flag](https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/#development) ?

Comment: Yeah, i wanted to implement something similar

Comment: You should probably start by having a look at what they are doing, since neither of them is using `os.exec*` functions. https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/gunicorn/reloader.py https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/tree/master/uvicorn/supervisors